# Photoelectric emission

Tags: experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect

We know that at stopping potential the current is zero. Also the stopping potential is zero when the frequency of the incident light is equal to the threshold frequency. In the graph given below, for frequency less than threshold frequency, the value of stopping potential is negative. Does that mean that if we apply a potential difference more negative than the stopping potential for that frequency (which is less than threshold frequency), then there will be some value of some photoelectric current? Please explain.
[Graph-stopping potential vs frequency of incident light](http://cdn1.askiitians.com/cms-content/common/www.askiitians.comonlineteststudymaterial_images16_frequencyVsstoppingpotential.JPG.jpg)

[image]

Comment: What is there to be downrated? If you don't know the answer, then why you downrate it?

Comment: No.  No current if the photon energy does not exceed the work function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a negative difference does not work. You need enough positive energy to knock electrons loose from the surface. In the photo electric cell the electrons that are being knocked loose need to cross the gap to the collector plate and only then is a current created in the circuit.